# Why is sizeof(int*) = 8 in C# and sizeof(int*) = 4 in C++

Tags: c#, c++

C#

```
 sizeof(int*)
 8
```

C++

```
 sizeof(int*)
 4
```

Why is this? Also sizeof long in C# is 8. In C++ it is 4.

Comment: sizeof(int*) is not 4 in C++

Comment: What makes you think they SHOULD be the same between different languages? And more importantly, are you compiling for the same processor architecture? On my target system at work, `long` is 32 bits, on my computer I'm using now, it's either 32 or 64 depending on whether I compile for x86-32 or x86-64.

Comment: It's set for Any CPU in my C# project. In C++ it's set to Win32. I figured the size returned would be OS defined, rather than language

Comment: On 64-bit OS you can run 32-bit apps, but you can't run 64-bit apps on 32-bit OS.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, there is no such thing as "sizeof long is 4 in C++". "sizeof long" is implementation defined, and the only restriction is that it must be >= sizeof int. For the actual value of sizeof long check your C++ compiler documentation. For example, Visual C++ has sizeof long documented to be 4 at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple: You are getting the size of the pointer types. 8 would be an appropriate size for a 64 bit application.  4 would be appropriate for a 32 bit application.

One would presume you are running C# code using a 64bit .net and 32 bit C++ code.

Comment: Thanks all answers make sense. Just went with the democratic choice for best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling your `C#` program on `64-bit` and the `C++` one on `32-bit`.

Answer (score 1):

Size of pointers depends on processor architecture. On 32-bit all pointers are 32 bit (4 bytes). On 64-bit they are 64 bits (8 bytes).

You must have compared 64-bit C# app with 32-bit C++ app.

`long` is a different type in C# and in C++. [In C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) it's a 32-bit integer. [In C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) it's 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of OS and compiler, and settings of the compiler, will determine what size pointers and other types are. In all modern 64-bit processors, the processor (and most OSes) support running both 32- and 64-bit executables, so depending on the settings, you can get a 32- or a 64-bit pointer size [and other types may or may not change, depending on which compiler and OS combination it is].

The reason that C, C# and C++ do not have fixed sizes for these things is to allow the language to be compiled for a large number of different processors - including "weird" ones with 24-bit integer size or 9 bit characters (and 36-bit `int`)